# Does Errbit log delayed job errors out of the box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, errbit

Does delayed job work out of the box with Errbit? We had some failing jobs on the production environment and we can see in the delayed_job.log file some tasks failed along with their error message, but we didn't receive any errbit about it.

Does it work out of the box, or should we use DJ's hooks to wire it with Errbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since errbit uses the same notifier that Airbrake, you can use something as in the example hook in the delayed job readme https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#hooks.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to bother with writing your own hooks you can use the [delayed-plugins-airbrake](http://rubygems.org/gems/delayed-plugins-airbrake) gem.
This has to be only installed and registered in a simple initializer to easily catch all errors occuring in delayed jobs.